# Upgrading IntelliJ IDEA after Sierra Upgrade: does not have write access to /private/var

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, macos-sierra

Trying to upgrade Intellij IDEA from 2016.2 to 2016.2.5 and I am getting this error:

> IDEA does not have write access to
>   /private/var/folders/_q/7md3pcy10x9cxjdt9nzxjvdr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/97E0DA6A-73B2-4439-91AE-F7DD0353F063/d/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents

I can't modify the permissions of that folder because it is read-only. I've tried `chown` and `chmod` as root, neither of which work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after talking to Jetbrains support, there's nothing that can be done as they can't duplicate the issue and not enough people have reported it. The patch process doesn't work but you can just download the latest version. Problem solved.

Comment: Of all great answers below, this is not the right one to pin as the solution :) For everyone reading this, please, scroll down.

Answer (score 77):

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/
sudo chmod -R 777 IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/
```

these commands work recursively and fix the trouble

Comment: Thanks, the other answered didn't work for me but this worked!

Comment: Works for me. also ensure that you're starting IDEA from exactly that location.

Comment: This answer also works for the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA (2018.3.x) on macOS Mojave.  I have the Ultimate edition instead of the community edition, so the commands were:
`sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/`
`sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/`

Comment: For WebStorm the commands are following:
`sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/WebStorm.app/ &&
 sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/WebStorm.app/`

Comment: Similarly for pycharm: ```sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/PyCharm.app/ && sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/PyCharm.app/```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me as well. Should be marked as the best response.

Comment: Mine is `IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app` now

Comment: I got `xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Great!
Used this on OSX version 12.6.5 to allow Pycharm and Datagrip to do in-app updating.

Comment: For Rubymine `sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Rubymine.app/ && sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/Rubymine.app`

Answer (score 42):

This is happening because of some new security feature in Sierra.   I found some information about it here http://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/app-translocation.html

The work around I used was to go to the Application directory where the Intellij app was and delete the xattr com.apple.quarantine from the app.  This stops the app from opening up in that read only directory.

ex.

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine IntelliJ\ IDEA.app
```

Comment: Worked like a (Py)charm!  Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me. I had to run this:
'cd /Applications && xattr -d com.apple.quarantine IntelliJ\ IDEA.app` and then restart IntelliJ

Comment: Just an additional comment: If (like me) your domain user had changed, you will also have to re-set permissions IN ADDITION to the trick above.

Comment: I think it changed in newer versions: 
`$ sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/` ==> `xattr: IntelliJ IDEA CE.app: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine`

Comment: No such file... I'm using Mojave 10.14.1

Answer (score 39):

I know this is quite an old post, but I found a quick solution in MacOS.

1. Navigate to your .app file, and view the contents of it.
2. Right click on the "Contents" folder, and go to "Get Info".
3. Hit the Lock () icon to enable changes and enter your user password
4. In the permissions section, select "Read & write" for each element.
5. Click the three dots (...) icon and select "Apply to enclosed files and folders".
6. Restart IntelliJ.

This solved the problem for me, hope it helps others too!

Comment: Thanks! Btw, hit the lock icon first before step 3.

Comment: Also, I had to click the (...) icon and press "apply to enclosed folders".

Comment: I am not able to find "Apply to enclosed files and folders".

Comment: @Mehul Parmar It might have changed and become the default for the newer MacOS versions. Either way, `chmod 755 "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents"` should do the trick for you as suggested in @axnet's answer below.

Comment: Worked for me, and in MacOS Ventura 13.6 you can go to Finder > Applications > Right click on the webstorm icon > select "Show Package Contents" > Right click on the "Contents" folder > Select "Get info" > Expand the "Sharing & Permissions" > Give "Read & Write" privilege to your account

Comment: In addition to adding R/W privilege to Contents, I had to change the same for IntelliJ IDEA app as well.

Answer (score 24):

If you face this issue in MacOS Mojave, then you should execute following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/
```

Comment: this did it for me. xattr did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I faced the same problem while updating IntelliJ IDEA in Mac OS Catalina.
Actually it's a problem with folder permissions.
I followed the steps below and the upgrade was successful.

1. Open ***Finder*** and click on ***Applications*** in the left side pane.
2. Find ***IntelliJ IDEA*** and do right click and select ***Show Package Contents***.
3. Right click on the displayed ***Contents*** folder and select **Get Info**.
4. In the opened dialog box expand ***Sharing and Permissions*** section.
5. Then look for a pad lock icon at the right bottom.
6. Click on the pad lock icon to unlock it using Touch ID or Password to change permissions.
7. Look at the ***Sharing and Permissions*** section, ***Read & Write*** will be there only for system and ***Read only*** will be there for other users(Admin/Everyone).
8. So change the permission to ***Read & Write*** for other users too(Admin/Everyone).
9. Click the settings icon(Gear Icon) in the bottom and choose ***Apply to enclosed items...*** to make same permission settings for all the folders/files inside the ***Contents*** folder.
10. Then close the dialog box.
11. Open IntelliJ IDEA, in menu bar select ***IntelliJ IDEA->Check for Updates...*** to update.

Now it will update without any errors...

Comment: This works for me. I am on macOS BigSur 11.4

Comment: Tnx, this worked fine. Instead of allowing 'Everyone' I've added myself to the list with Read & Write permissions

Comment: this helped me too, because I have 2 users on my machine and the second user seems doesn't have full read/write permissions

Comment: That worked for Ventura 13.6.

Answer (score 5):

I've just encountered something very similar while testing jar updates with my app AuctionSieve.

The problem occurs when you run the app from the Downloads folder and try to do the update - it gets FileNotFoundExceptions because the entire folder macOS creates under /private/var/folders is a read-only **filesystem**. You can't change the permissions of the files at all.

Moving the app from the Downloads folder to the Applications folder solved the problem!

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to the Applications directory (on root) and give the rights to IntelliJ IDEA to read, write and execute its files.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/
```

Comment: chmod 775 wasn't sufficient in my case. This one with 777 did it.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use this CLI command to update everything.

`$ brew cask reinstall intellij-idea`.

Answer (score 2):

For `macOSBigSur(Apple M1)` I have solved by giving write permission to the `Contents` folder in IntelliJ.

```
1. From Finder click on Applications and search for IntelliJ IDEA CE. 
   Right-click on it and select show package contents options.
2. Right-click on the Contents folder and select Get Info.
3. Navigate to Sharing & Permissions and change the permission to Read/Write 
   for other users.
4. Click on the Settings icon(with three dots) at the bottom and 
   select Apply to enclosed items... to give the same permission 
   for all the folders and files inside the Contents folder.
```

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to just use the Jetbrains Toolbox to do the whole upgrade. Worked like a charm, didn't need any command line incantations or mucking about with OS folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the only thing that I do was the next:

```
$ brew cask reinstall intellij-idea.
```

After that I open the IntelliJ and select the option related with import previous config.

That new version is able to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/
```

this command works for the newer versions

Answer (score 1):

Similar for GoLand, find your Goland app dir

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/GoLand.app 
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/GoLand.app
```

Comment: xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Finder or it's menu bar (Go)
Open Applications
Ctrl+Click (right-click) PyCharm (jetbrains .app)
click get info
at the bottom, expand permissions
unlock the padlock
change all three to "read&write" to allow app to make changes to sys
lock the padlock
restart the application

There were several engineers stating the "systemtools" had to be updated in the virtual environment whether by pip or interpreter pckg mgr.

For me, it turned out to be the fact that the imports were supposed to be local, thus be pulled from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well on my Mac Os. The problem is that IntelliJ was mounted as a disk image at every start. I added to the application menu bar the installer or I don't know what. I then started the app from the application list and the problem was solved.
So be sure you are not mounting an image

Answer (score 0):

All of the above workarounds caused other problems in my case.
The best solution for me was to use the **Jetbrains Toolbox** application.
It updated my IntelliJ Idea to 2023.3.2 and fixed the errors for me.

https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/