# Failure on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 updates

Tags: intellij-idea

macOS Ventura 13.2.1
My current IDEA version is 2022.3.3
[image]

Do you know how to resolve the issue if I want to update to v 2023.1?
Thank you

Comment: Please try suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43390391/12844632